# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, multithreading, uialertview

I have a thread dispatched through GCD. When the thread completes, I present a UIAlertView to let the user know that the thread is complete. I execute the UIAlertView on the main thread ([NSThread mainThread]).

If I remain in the View Controller the alert view appears fine and when I press the [Ok] button it disappears as it should. However, if I return to the main view controller (thus popping the prior view controller from the stack) I get the above error message after clicking [Ok]. The AlertView displays properly and correctly closes.

Can I assume that this has nothing to do with the UIAlartView and that perhaps the issue is with some other code attempting to execute after the alartview? Even so, I can't see anything after that block of code that would be executing. I guess at this point, I'm just trying to confirm that if the AlertView works properly then the problem is not with that.

If I can simplify this to a small chunk of sample code I'll post that here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you set the alert view's `delegate` to `self` (the view controller). So if the view controller is dismissed before the alert view, the alert view tries to contact its (now reallocated) delegate.

Simply pass `nil` to the alert view `delegate` instead of `self`. This assumes you don't actually need to handle the OK button.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help. Sometimes the answers are really simple but really invisible!

Comment: Thanks @mmaddy. However, in many cases, for example my app, we need to handle the "OK" button, how do we deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To use the delegate and avoid the EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you can add a property like

`@property (nonatomic, weak) UIAlertView *myAlertView;`

to your view controller, and assign the alert view to it. Then, in your view controller's dealloc method add

```
- (void)dealloc {
    // other dealloc code
    if (self == self.myAlertView.delegate) self.myAlertView.delegate = nil;
}
```